# Representing every positive integer using floor function and square number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For a real number $x$, $\lfloor x\rfloor=\max\{n\in\mathbb{Z}\mid n\leq x\}.$

**Question** : Every positive integer can be expressed as $\left\lfloor\frac{(mt+r)^2}{m}\right\rfloor$ for some positive integer $m$ and integer $t\ge 0$ and integer $r$ is between $1\le r < m$.

Example: $10=\left\lfloor\frac{(6\times 1+2)^2}{6}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{(8 \times 1+1)^2}{8}\right\rfloor$

Clearly, every square number is expressible in this way.

For integers, verified upto $10^5$.

*Edit*, **Extended Question**: For fix positive integer $k$, Every positive integer can be expressed as $\left\lfloor\frac{(mt+r)^k}{m}\right\rfloor$ for some positive integer $m$ and integer $t\ge 0$ and integer $r$ is between $1\le r < m$.

Observation and Claim: We can express $\left\lfloor\frac{(mt+r)^k}{m}\right\rfloor$ as a polynomial in terms of $mt+r$ as $$\left\lfloor\frac{(mt+r)^k}{m}\right\rfloor=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(x_it+y_i)(mt+r)^i$$

Such that $x_i\equiv r^{k-1-i}\pmod{m}$ for $i=0,1,...k-1$ and $y_i=\left\lfloor\frac{x_ir}{m}\right\rfloor$.

The proof of above observation maybe helpful here to find solution for question.

Welcome to all your suggestions, comments, edits and solutions. Thanks.

Comment: I think it may help to simply your expression to $mt^2+2tr+\lfloor \frac {r^2}m\rfloor$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that as [lulu's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4856282/representing-every-positive-integer-using-floor-function-and-square-number#comment10350116_4856282) suggests, the expression simplifies to

$$mt^2 + 2rt + \left\lfloor\frac{r^2}{m}\right\rfloor$$

For $n \le 3$, have $t = 0$, so the result is $\left\lfloor\frac{r^2}{m}\right\rfloor$. Then for $n = 1$, we can use $m = 3$, $r = 2$. With $n = 2$, there's $m = 4$, $r = 3$. Finally, for $n = 3$, we can use $m = 5$, $r = 4$.

With $n \gt 3$, using $t = r = 1$ and $m = n - 2$, since $m \gt 1$ so $\frac{r^2}{m} \lt 1 \;\to\; \left\lfloor\frac{r^2}{m}\right\rfloor = 0$, the above expression becomes

$$(n - 2)(1^2) + 2(1)(1) + 0 = n$$

---

Alternatively, as indicated in [peterwhy's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4856282/representing-every-positive-integer-using-floor-function-and-square-number/4856299?noredirect=1#comment10350134_4856299), a somewhat simpler solution which works for all $n \ge 1$ is to use $m = n + 2$, $t = 0$ and $r = m - 1$ which gives

$$\left\lfloor\frac{(m - 1)^2}{m}\right\rfloor = m - 2 + \left\lfloor\frac{1^2}{m}\right\rfloor = (n + 2) - 2 + 0 = n$$

---

For the more general case of your extended question, i.e., expressing all positive integers $n$ in the form

$$n = \left\lfloor\frac{(mt+r)^k}{m}\right\rfloor$$

for a fixed positive integer $k$, this can also always be done. For $k = 1$, choose $t = n$, $m = 2$ and $r = 1$. For $k \ge 2$, using $t = 0$, we get

$$n = \left\lfloor\frac{r^k}{m}\right\rfloor$$

Choose any positive integer $r$ where $r \ge n - 1$ and $r^{k} \ge (r + 1)n$. Then there's an integer $m \ge r + 1 \;\to\; r \le m - 1 \;\to\; n \le m$, and an integer $0 \le a \lt n \;\to\; 0 \le a \lt m$, where

$$r^k = mn + a \;\;\to\;\; \frac{r^k}{m} = n + \frac{a}{m} \;\;\to\;\; \left\lfloor\frac{r^k}{m}\right\rfloor = n$$

Comment: Your pattern for $n\le 3$, where $t=0$ and $r=m-1$, also extends to larger $n$ similarly as $$\left\lfloor\frac{(m-1)^2}{m}\right\rfloor = m - 2 + \left\lfloor\frac{1^2}{m}\right\rfloor$$ for $n=m-2$.

Comment: @peterwhy Thank you for your great suggestion. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: thank you so much, can we  extend this to all integer power?

Comment: @Pruthviraj You're welcome. Yes, we can extend this to all integer powers $k$, as I've shown in my updated answer.